# database for grasping include raw sensor data?

Tags: ros, household-objects-database, grasping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am doing some research on robot grasping. Now I need a database with object models and the raw sensor data(point cloud). As far as I know, there are 3 databases that I can use, "cgdb", "household_objects_database", and "KIT ObjectModels Web Database". But for cgdb and household_objects_database, it seems that no raw sensor data are included. Is this the case? Where can i find corresponding sensor data for these objects.

I also need to use Graspit! simulator to test the grasp of a certain robot hand on the objects in the database. I think I would need an interface between Graspit! and these databases for the conversion of the object format . Anyone knows if there is an existing interface or do i have to write my own?

Not sure if it is a good place to ask. Please advise me if so. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10490/database-for-grasping-include-raw-sensor-data?/) by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2011-07-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The household_objects_database has a companion dataset, the Grasp Playpen dataset, which also contains real life sensor data for some of the objects:

http://bags.willowgarage.com/downloads/grasp_playpen_dataset/grasp_playpen_dataset.html

For a GraspIt interface, and if you are already familiar with ROS, try the experimental version of GraspIt included with ROS diamondback. You should be able to get it either from debs or from source code:

sudo apt-get-install ros-diamondback-graspit-simulator

https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/graspit_simulator/trunk

---

Originally posted by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) with karma: 586 on 2011-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-07-13**:
Thanks I'll have a try

**Comment by [Matei Ciocarlie](https://answers.ros.org/users/36/matei-ciocarlie/) on 2011-07-11**:
You should be able to have both installed on your system, and use one or the other. However, the new version makes it easier to integrate with ROS both from a build standpoint and as far as running them together. The new version inside the graspit_simulator ROS stack is the on that future GraspIt releases will be coming from.

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-07-09**:
I've asked Kaijen to fix the permission problem. The "graspit-simulator" appears to be a modified version of the original Graspit! to integrate with ROS. As I already have the original oen, I was wondering if the two versions could work together, will there be any conflict? thanks

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-07-07**:
I was trying to download the data following the instructions on the ‘playpen_dataset’ link you mentioned. But it says ERROR 403: Forbidden, 'You don't have permission to access'. Do you know how can I get access to this server? Thank you

**Comment by [vincent](https://answers.ros.org/users/280/vincent/) on 2011-07-06**:
Thanks, I'll try this